# Crystal Reports - Horizontal page numbering

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports Developer XI

I have a crosstab report. The crosstab can span many pages horizontally. For a report 10 pages wide and 3 pages long, I display page numbers as '1-1 of 3' through '3-10 of 3' but I'd like to be able to display them as '1 of 30' through '30 of 30'.

Unfortunately the Page N of M field only displays the vertical page numbers. In this case, adding the Page N of M field gives me "Page 1 of 3" across the first ten horizontal pages, then "Page 2 of 3" across the next ten pages, and "Page 3 of 3" across the last ten pages.

Unfortunately the Page N of M field displays the same information whether or not the "Repeat on Horizontal Pages" property is selected.

Answer (score 3):

In your Field Explorer, go to **Special Fields->Horizontal Page Number** and insert that.  I've never used it myself, but it seems to be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special field called "Page N of M".  Drag that onto your page and that should give you the numbering scheme that you're after.

**Edited to add:**  Sorry, I read your post and didn't "read" your post.  The problem is that these aren't really pages but a continuation of a page or virtual pages.  What if you were to use Page N of M and right-click that on your pageview and go to the format editor.  Try selecting, "Repeat on Horizontal Pages" from the Common tab and see what type of behavior you get from that.

Otherwise, I don't know if it's possible without a complicated formula.

Comment: Unfortunately the Page N of M field only displays the vertical page numbers.  In this case, adding the Page N of M field gives me "Page 1 of 3" across the first ten horizontal pages, then "Page 2 of 3" across the next ten pages, and "Page 3 of 3" across the last ten pages.