# Horizontal page numbering in Crystal Reports cross tab

Tags: crystal-reports, pivot, crosstab, page-numbering

With reference to the question [Horizontal Page Numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338583/crystal-reports-horizontal-page-numbering), is there any way to print similar horizontal page numbers as '1-1 of 3' through '3-10 of 3' or '1 of 30' through '30 of 30' (any one of these modes will do) in cross tab spanning multiple horizontal pages in **Crystal Reports v 9.2?**